# Is it possible to transfer tokens to account declared in remaining accounts?

Tags: solana, anchor-solana, solana-transaction-instruction

Try to transfer tokens to one of the account declared in `remaining_accounts` list.

Here's the way I create CpiContext:

```rust
let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(), 
    Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.account_x.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.remaining_accounts.first().unwrap().to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.owner.to_account_info().clone()
  });
```

I got error related to `CpiContext` lifetime mismatch. Exact log error: `lifetime mismatch ...but data from ctx flows into ctx here`.

Why I want to use remaining accounts to transfer tokens? This transfer is optional depending on whether user decides to pass the account (referral links/affiliation). Other methods than passing account as remaining accounts to implement the optional transfer will be also highly appreciated.

Comment: Resolved my problem by manipulating Rust's lifetime in instruction as in answer. You can checkout entire implementation here: https://github.com/invariant-labs/protocol/pull/219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you help out Rust's lifetime inference in your instruction:

```
pub fn your_instruction<'info>(ctx: Context<'_, '_, '_, 'info, YourContext<'info>>, ...)
```

Comment: Yep, that's solution. I will also present entire code as It's open-source. Thank you